# Can't ping service inside Docker container from the host machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running a container via `docker-compose` on Ubuntu 20.04, and I can't ping or curl the web server that's running inside from the host machine that's running docker.

I've given the container a static IP, and if I open a shell in the container I can see the service running fine and curl it as expected.

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  container:
    image: imagename
    container_name: container
    networks:
      net:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.5
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/London
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
     config:
       - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
         gateway: 172.20.0.1
```

But if I `curl -v 172.20.0.5:9000` from the same machine, I get

```
*   Trying 172.20.0.5:9000...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 172.20.0.5 port 9000 failed: No route to host
* Failed to connect to 172.20.0.5 port 9000: No route to host
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.20.0.5 port 9000: No route to host
```

My best guess is something to do with iptables or firewall rules? I've not changed those at all from the default Docker set up. With `host` network mode it does work, but exposes the 9000 port publicly. I want to have it only accessible locally and then set it up behind a reverse proxy. Thanks.

Comment: Can your container ping 172.20.0.1 and other IPs on its host?

Comment: The command for connecting to a docker container is  `docker exec -it container /bin/bash` .  And then you execute the `ping` command.